# What is the expected magnitude of the third Wieferich-prime?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

A Wieferich-prime is a prime $p$ with the property $$2^{p-1}\equiv 1\ \pmod{p^2} $$

The only known Wieferich-primes are $1093$ and $3511$. Various search limits
are mentioned in the internet. Here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime

the largest search limit is claimed to be $6.7\times 10^{15}$, but $3\times 10^{17}$ is also mentioned.

> Is the later limit already reached or in progress ?

Despite the rarity of Wieferich-primes it is conjectured that there are
infinite many.

> What is the expected magnitude of the third Wieferich-prime considering the
>     largest search limits ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the literal answer to the second question surprising and funny.

One might expect that the residue class $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}\mod p$ should act as if it is determined uniformly at random. So a random prime $p$ is Wieferich with probability $\frac{1}{p}$. Since the probability that a random integer $n$ is prime is about $\frac{1}{\log n}$, this suggests that the number of Wieferich primes less than $x$ should grow like
$$
\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n\log n}\sim \log\log x.
$$
In particular, there are expected to be infinitely many Wieferich primes because $\log\log x\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

If we pick some integer $N$, how large is the next largest Wieferich prime after $N$? The "probability" that the next largest Wieferich prime is $n$ is about
$$
\frac{1}{n\log n} \cdot \prod_{m=N+1}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{m\log m}\right)\sim\frac{1}{n\log n}\frac{\log N}{\log n}.
$$
The expected value of the magnitude of the next Wieferich prime after $N$ is
$$
\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty n\cdot\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}\frac{\log N}{\log n}\right)=\log N\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{(\log n)^2}=+\infty.
$$
So even though we expect there are infinitely many Wieferich primes, the expected magnitude of the next one is infinite!

Comment: $$\large log(log(10^{10^{100}}))\approx 231$$, so $231$ Wieferich-primes below a googol-plex should exists. Even if the estimate is drastically reduced, it should be still greater than $3$.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely weird. If we know there are only two Wieferich primes below $3\times 10^{17}$, then the likelihood that the next one is less than $10^{1750}$ is greater than $99\%$. I still stand by the conclusion that according to the probabilistic model, the expected value of the size of the next one is infinite.

Comment: OK, the likelihood of $0,99$ should come nearer to the truth. Such "paradoxes" occur often in probability theory : The number of throws of a fair coin until the number of heads and the number of tails coincide, is infinite in the average, although the probability that the tie is eventually reached, is $1$.